# Activity, actions and flags

Tags: discussion, flags, profile-page

Why don't the flags raised appear in the activity section? After all they are "Actions"/"activity".

I know they appear under the *"Flagged posts for ..."* (why "for" and not "by"?) section, but it still counts as an action, doesn't it?

Comment: Probably because the activity tab is meant to be publicly accessible information about your activity, and your flags are private.

Comment: Well, there is the votes tab, which is visible only to you, and the responses tab, which is visible only to you and moderators. If flags were to be moved to a tab, it'd be more appropriate to place them in a dedicated flags tab.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn yeah, that came to me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the actions reported under *Activity* are public. Other users can see everything in that section. Flags you have raised, on the other hand, are private, and other users cannot see them.

This may have been reason enough not to display them together.

Comment: To add to this.. in the event that you raise a flag for moderator attention, you definitely don't want that to be displayed publicly.